# are there way how to set UserAgent each url on wkwebview of iOS without re-instanciating?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to set UserAgent each url on wkwebview.
But i can't find.

```
let userAgentStr = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let dic:NSDictionary = ["UserAgent":userAgentStr]
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(dic as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

if above source is,my app will not be able to change UserAgent as long as i set nil wkwebview.

I don't want to re-instaciate wkwebview when i want to change useragent.

are there way how to set UserAgent each url on wkwebview of iOS without re-instanciating?

Answer (score 0):

This was not possible with iOS 8 but on iOS 9 there actually is a `customUserAgent` on the `WKWebView` object. So you can just set that and it will be set for every connection the `WKWebView` makes.